# Code transfer in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I worked on a console code, that basically asks the user for their Iban, and then searchs on a linked list what is their bank name and code of agent. This is a plain C++ console application. Now, I have to do an interface with Qt and I was wondering if I could use the code I have and just work with the GUI or if I need to transfer the code (for example, instead of `string`, use `QString`).

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to say without seeing any code, however I think it should be quite straightforward for you to integrate your code with Qt. Qt supplies quite many "helper-functions" to convert between STL objects and Qt objects such as for example QString:

```
std::string toStdString() const
QString fromStdString(const std::string &str)
```

Comment: The only thing i need to do is ask the user by interface a string, and then return a string, the program is working without on console, for what I am understanding i just need to do the interface using QT and then i use the code i have without changing it, because the code is a bit long, and for me to transfer it all to QT library would take a lot of time.

Comment: @Charles I'm not sure what you mean by "transfer". You can mix Qt with STL without any problems. Using at QLineEdit will give you a QString but that's easy to convert to a std::string, by using the function I wrote in my answer. As long as performance is not extremely important you probably don't need to change any code you've done so far. I think you should just go for it.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` and console code are separate issues. You can certainly write console code using Qt, in fact there's quite a bit of such code out there, doing its work. You can easily create `QString` from `std::string`. The simplest answer is: yes, you can use the code, and the generality of that answer makes the question useless. There's no other way but to answer "yes".